# How do you know if “by inspection” is a valid argument?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, arithmetic

Sometimes while certain deductions may seem obvious, they are only obvious because of much prior work.

For instance, even describing something as simple as $1+1=2$, you would first need to:

- define group containing a set of objects $S$,
- define the operation of addition such that $S \times S \rightarrow S$,
- define that the set is closed under this operation $(S_{1},S_{2}) \rightarrow S_{1}+S_{2}$,
- define that addition is associative $(S_{1}+S_{2})+S_{3}=S_{1}+(S_{2}+S_{3})$,

and it even continues on from there.

So, if you can't even argue “by inspection” for something as elementary as $1+1=2$, what exactly makes it valid for more complex derivations dealing with summations or matrices or special functions of a complex variable and etc.?

Comment: You don't need to show that $+$ is an operation of a group, you just need to *define* $+$ (and $1$ and $2$). It can be the case that $1+1=2$ even if addition isn't associative, say.

Comment: "By inspection" is a nice way of saying "this is obvious and shouldn't need a lengthy explanation."

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2 is a definition, so I don't understand what it has to do with proof by inspection or any other kind of proof. Definitions are not subject to being proven.

Comment: $1+1=2$ is clearly a definition. $2+2=4$ is a theorem.

Comment: @SeanRoberson - that is definitely incorrect. "By inspection" may be used when something must verified in a finite number of cases (for example: for each regular polyhedron); the proof may be very different in each case, but if all the proofs are correct, and it is known (from other work, or from first principles) that only those finitely many cases are possible, the overall statement is proved.

Comment: @mathguy I've definitely seen it used both ways. I think the way you describe is the "proper" way, but it is also used as "just prove this bit yourself, I'm busy."

Comment: @NoahSchweber - what you describe is not necessarily disjoint from what I said. If you are too busy and you want me to prove the bit by myself, but the proof would involve induction (say), then you shouldn't tell me to prove it "by inspection". (That would definitely be improper on your part.) If you are too busy to check, you can ask me to verify by inspection that there are no prime numbers between 200 and 210. Let me take each one of those numbers and show their lowest prime divisor. That would be OK. Ask me to prove there are infinitely many primes, but don't ask me to do it by inspection.

Comment: @SeanRoberson But that's the problem is "shouldn't" is subjective, not logical.

Comment: By "prior work" do you mean prior in the particular paper or book? In which case you would say something like "by inspection ... (recall that such and such from earlier)". But if you're going to be a Sheldon Cooper to someone over basic arithmetic, your problem is social rather than mathematical.

Answer (score 7):

I'll give two explanations, not completely unrelated. In the vein of Sean Roberson's comment, it often is intended in an informal sense that the result can be shown with a bit of thought. To answer your question in that case, you choose to use it by gearing it to your target audience. If you have a subproof (that you've produced yourself and) that is uninteresting and for which you expect the readers to be able to provide themselves, then using "by inspection" may be appropriate.

At the complete opposite end of formality, consider mechanized theorem provers like Coq, Isabelle/HOL, Mizar, and Agda. In at least the ones based on dependent type theory, like Coq and Agda, a potentially huge (but finite) amount of computation can go into verifying a single step of a proof. In Agda, you might define the natural numbers as follows:

```
data Nat : Set where
    Z : Nat
    S : Nat -> Nat
```

with addition then defined recursively as follows:

```
_+_ : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
x + Z = x
x + (S y) = S (x + y)
```

We can define $1$ and $2$ via:

```
one : Nat
one = S Z

two : Nat
two = S (S Z)
```

We can then prove that `one + one` equals `two` via:

```
one_plus_one_equals_two : Id (one + one) two
one_plus_one_equals_two = Refl
```

where, for completeness, `Id` is defined as:

```
data Id {A : Set} (x : A) : A -> Set
    Refl : Id x x
```

To verify that `one_plus_one_equals_two` is well-typed, and thus, effectively, a valid proof, we need to know whether `one + one` is the same as `two`. To do this, Agda computes `one + one` and `two` to normal form. If they have the same normal form, then they are considered the same. In this case, that normal form is `S (S Z)`. Note that it does require some computation via the definition of `+` to reduce `one + one` to `S (S Z)`.<sup>1</sup>

You do not need to justify the steps of computation. A mechanized proof checker for Agda is expected to be able to perform these computations itself. This is one formal perspective on steps which might be said to be show "by inspection". Indeed, often statements that are asserted to be try "by inspection" *are* straight computations. This is largely consistent with mathguy's comment. In other words, if it is a purely mechanical computation, then "by inspection" would almost certainly be reasonable. For an informal proof, you'd still want to tailor this to your audience. There are a surprisingly large number of things that can be verified purely mechanically. I recommend the book [A=B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) for some non-trivial examples. I probably would spell out some of the details of the equality of two hypergeometric series, even though they are mechanical verifiable.

For example, checking whether two polynomials with rational coefficients are equal is a purely mechanical process. If my proof relied on the fact that two polynomial expressions were equal, I would not painstakingly go through a step by step argument in terms of the axioms of commutative ring theory. I would just throw them into a computer algebra system to make sure, and then just assert that they are equal with little to no argument in the informal proof. With a little care, you can arrange it so that Agda can compute the proof that two polynomials are equal. This is what the [RingSolver](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/%5C?n=Libraries.UsingTheRingSolver) module does. Doing so leaves a potentially large and non-trivial computation to the proof checker, but it is a completely mechanical process that's completely specified by the computational rules that are part of the definition of Agda itself. This is a formal analogue of leaving it up to the reader to check the equality of two polynomials.

<sup>1</sup> Note that Agda can't solve just any equality automatically. If you ask it the equivalent of whether `x + Z` = `x`, it will happily immediately say it is via the first line of the definition of `+`. However, if you ask it the equivalent of whether `Z + x` = `x`, it is unable to show this just by computation. The definition of `+` does not specify how to handle the case where the second argument is a variable.

Comment: Upvoting not for the mention of my comment, but for really expanding it and putting into words what I couldn't. Most of "by inspection" is interpreted in my mind as "left to the reader," "one can show...", or even "hey dummy, you should be able to do this."